# How to generate monthly period index with annual frequency?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, subsampling, pandas-timeindex

How would generate in the most concise way a monthly period index that is observed only every 12 months?

I came up with the following solution

```
pd.period_range(start=pd.Period('1975-07'), 
                end=pd.Period('1985-07'),
                freq='M'
                ).to_frame().iloc[::12].index
```

but I was wondering if there is a way that avoids the conversion from period index to dataframe and back to period index.

This is the expected output:

```
PeriodIndex(['1975-07', '1976-07', '1977-07', '1978-07', '1979-07', '1980-07',
             '1981-07', '1982-07', '1983-07', '1984-07', '1985-07'],
            dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `freq='12M'`:

```
pd.period_range(start=pd.Period('1975-07'), 
                end=pd.Period('1985-07'),
                freq='12M'
                )
```

Comment: Is there a way to adjust the output to have the frequency 'M' as opposed to '12M'?